# Composing validation annotations into a single annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations, annotation-processing

I have the below method which uses nameId as a RequestHeader and there are other methods that use the same variable declaration. Is there a way that the `nameId` validations can be grouped into an interface so that we can annotate instead of adding @Valid & @Pattern every time?

```
public ResponseEntity<PlanResponse> updatePlanProductByPlanId(
        @RequestHeader(value = "name_id", required = true) @Valid @Pattern(regexp = REGEX_PATTERN_ALPHANUMERIC, message = "{error.invalid.name.id.header}") String nameId,
        @PathVariable(value = "planid") @Valid @Pattern(regexp = REGEX_PATTERN_ONLY_NUMBERS, message = "{error.invalid.plan.id}") String planId,
        @Validated({
            OnPlanProductUpdate.class }) @RequestBody(required = true) SavePlanProductRequest updateProductRequest)
        throws ServiceException { ... }
```

Expecting something like `@NameId` annotation.

```
public ResponseEntity<PlanResponse> updatePlanProductByPlanId(
        @RequestHeader(value = "name_id", required = true) @NameId String nameId,
        @PathVariable(value = "planid") @Valid @Pattern(regexp = REGEX_PATTERN_ONLY_NUMBERS, message = "{error.invalid.plan.id}") String planId,
        @Validated({
            OnPlanProductUpdate.class }) @RequestBody(required = true) SavePlanProductRequest updateProductRequest)
        throws ServiceException { ... }
```

I tried creating an interface like the one below, but the validation didn't seem to work.

```
@Valid 
@Pattern(regexp = REGEX_PATTERN_ALPHANUMERIC, message = "{error.invalid.name.id.header}") 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NameId {
       String nameId() default "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
@Pattern(regexp = REGEX_PATTERN_ALPHANUMERIC, message = "{error.invalid.name.id.header}") 
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface NameId {
       String nameId() default "";
}
```

I think the Constraint was missing, and the Valid annotation is not necessary.

Read more here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-constraint-composition